# Greatest common divisor of $(2^{21}-1,2^{27}-1)$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Find $\text{gcd}(2^{21}-1,2^{27}-1).$

**My proof:** We know that $2^{21}-1=(2^3)^7-1=8^7-1=(8-1)(8^6+\dots+8+1)=7(8^6+\dots+8+1)=7N_1$ and $2^{27}-1=(2^3)^9-1=8^9-1=(8-1)(8^8+\dots+8+1)=7(8^8+\dots+8+1)=7N_2.$ Also $N_2-N_1=8^8+8^7$. Hence $$\text{gcd}(2^{21}-1,2^{27}-1)=\text{gcd}(7N_1,7N_2)=7\text{gcd}(N_1,N_2).$$

I guess that $\text{gcd}(N_1,N_2)=1$ but I can't prove rigorously. Can anyone show a full proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $$\gcd(a^n-1,a^m-1)=a^{\gcd(n,m)}-1$$
So now $$\gcd(2^{21}-1,2^{27}-1)=2^{\gcd(21,27)}-1=7$$

---

We'll now prove the theorem I used here.

We can do the following. Assume $n>m$, then: \begin{align}
\gcd(a^n-1,a^m-1)&=\gcd((a^n-1)-(a^m-1),a^m-1)\\
&=\gcd(a^m(a^{n-m}-1),a^m-1)\\
\end{align}
since $\gcd(a^m,a^m-1)=1$, we now know
$$\gcd(a^n-1,a^m-1)=\gcd(a^{n-m}-1,a^m-1)$$
Now we can do Euclid's algorithm in the exponents! We obtain the final equality$$\gcd(a^n-1,a^m-1)=a^{\gcd(n,m)}-1$$

Comment: +1! It's very nice resut and I didn't know about it. Can you give a proof or reference to proof?

Comment: Edited the answer with a (in my opinion) quite elegant proof.

Comment: Nice proof! But can you explain the last sentence more deailed. What means "Now we can do Euclid's algorithm in the exponents"?

Comment: [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is based of a very basic theorem. For all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ (where $b\neq 0$), we can find $q,r\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $a=bq+r$, where $0\leq r<b$. Now if we wish to compute $\gcd(a,b)$, where $a>b$, then note that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$, and so we can reduce further and further until we reach the $\gcd$. To obtain $\gcd(r,b)$ from $\gcd(a,b)$ we only have to use $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)$ a couple times. Be aware of that this is no proof for anything, just a basic explaination of what the algorithm is.

Comment: Yes i know that! But how you got that $\text{gcd}(a^n-1,a^m-1)=a^{\text{gcd}(n,m)}-1$?

Comment: Since $\gcd(a^n-1,a^m-1)=\gcd(a^{n-m}-1,a^m-1)$, we can repeat this process (doing euclid's algorithm in the exponents to get $\gcd(n,m)$) to get $\gcd(a^n-1,a^m-1)=a^{\gcd(n,m)}-1$. I advice you to try following my proof with the numbers in your problem, you'll understand it better that way.

Comment: Dear! Thank you very much for your elegant proof. Just now I understood what did you mean :)